# How to enable NFC with Project Tango Development Tablet?

Tags: java, android, nfc, rfid, google-project-tango

I want to enable the NFC function for my Project Tango Development Tablet. I added the following lines to the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
```

And I added the following lines to my onCreate() function:

```
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(nfcAdapter != null && nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

But NFC is not available. I read that the Tango tablet has RFID/NFC hardware [here](https://developers.google.com/tango/hardware/tablet?hl=de). Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: Tango tablets definitely have NFC - I use it regularly, but haven't tried writing an app that uses it.

Comment: Did you enable NFC in the Settings app?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to check the settings.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer my own question. I forgot to enable NFC in the settings. You have to **turn on NFC, go to Settings>More...>NFC and switch it on**.